# JQuery form validation works but form won't submit

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

UPDATE:

I've found that the following allows me to submit the form. The difference seems to be the "else" portion, specifically returning '"true"' seems to make the submit happen. If I change that in any way I can't submit. However, if I leave that in it's not properly catching errors and preventing the form from submitting. Any advice on this?

NEW JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('#form-validate').validate(); {debug: false}    
$("[name^=customfields]").each(function(){
    $(this).rules("add", {
        remote: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "/xpath-evaluator.xqy",
            dataType: "json",
            dataFilter: function(data) {
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                if (json.status === 'false') {
                    return "\"" + json.error.split(')')[1] + "\"";

                }
                else {return '"true"';}
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have multiple fields I need to validate against a remote source. I'm using the code below which validates perfectly.

The point I'm stuck on is that the form won't submit when the fields are valid.

I've tried as many suggestions as I could find here on SO and via searching but haven't had any luck. The submit button simply doesn't do anything but put the cursor back in the first field it is validating when pressed.

I'm guessing I have a syntax error or am forgetting something. I've tried adding a submitHandler, but that didn't help nor did changing the name of my submit button to something other than submit. If anyone can point out my errors here and get me on the right track, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('#form-validate').validate();  
$("[name^=customfields]").each(function () {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        remote: {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/xpath-evaluator.xqy",
            dataFilter: function(data) {
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                if (json.status === 'false') {
                    return "\"" + json.error + "\"";
                }
                else{
                    return "\"" + " " + "\"";
                }
            }
        },
        debug: false
    });
});
```

});

Here's the Form:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-style-type" content="text/css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/APFavicon.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/css/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="navbar-search pull-left form-inline" action="process-form.xqy" id="form-validate">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input01">Fields:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="checkbox inline">Custom XPath: </label>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label class="inline">Custom Field 1 </label><input type="text" name="customfields.1" class="span6 input-large"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label class="inline">Custom Field 2 </label><input type="text" name="customfields.2" class="span6 input-large"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label class="inline">Custom Field 3 </label><input type="text" name="customfields.3" class="span6 input-large"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label class="inline">Custom Field 4 </label><input type="text" name="customfields.4" class="span6 input-large"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label class="inline">Custom Field 5 </label><input type="text" name="customfields.5" class="span6 input-large"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>   
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button name="newname" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>                
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/xpath-validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/force-page-refresh-onBack.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the layout of the form including the ACTION and METHOD?

Comment: I've included the form, thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure I've done this completely correctly, but I've gotten this working for our purposes and it's not producing any errors, maybe this can help someone in the future. Here's the working JavaScript.

As you'll see if you compare the above, I'm returning a boolean value of true if things are valid and instead of trying to parse json.status from my reponse, I'm parsing json.valid which is what turned out to be in the header. This may not be the same for everyone so I'd check that carefully. Both of these changes were needed to make the validation work and loop over multiple fields in my form as well as allow it to submit.

```
$('#form-validate').validate(); 
$("[name^=customfields]").each(function(){
    $(this).rules("add", {
        remote: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "/xpath-evaluator.xqy",
            dataType: "json",
            dataFilter: function(data) {
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                if (json.valid != false) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {return "\"" + json.error.split(')')[1] + "\"";}
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery Validate 1.13.0 (using Microsoft's jQuery Validation CDN -- source http://jqueryvalidation.org) it appears to work just fine after including the METHOD="get" attribute to the form and also 'required' to each field.

Both validation and the form submit works -- working example
http://jsfiddle.net/45Ju5/

```
<form class="navbar-search pull-left form-inline" action="process-form.xqy" id="form-validate" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="input01">Fields:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <label class="checkbox inline">Custom XPath: </label>
                <br/>
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="inline">Custom Field 1 </label><input type="text" name="customfields.1" class="span6 input-large" required />
                </div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="inline">Custom Field 2 </label><input type="text" name="customfields.2" class="span6 input-large" required />
                </div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="inline">Custom Field 3 </label><input type="text" name="customfields.3" class="span6 input-large" required />
                </div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="inline">Custom Field 4 </label><input type="text" name="customfields.4" class="span6 input-large" required />
                </div>
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="inline">Custom Field 5 </label><input type="text" name="customfields.5" class="span6 input-large" required />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button name="newname" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>                
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I still seem to have the problem. I think the fiddle submits because it's not actually getting any response back from the remote resource since it doesn't exist. If I "break" my validation my form also submits but of course it's not validating. Required works since it's built into the validate JQuery module. I'm wondering now if it isn't the response that is getting returned from the remote resource. We're returning JSON like: {"valid":true}, does this looks correct?

Comment: So you're not using the built-in jQuery Validation?  Which package are you using (or are you 'rolling your own')?

Comment: I am using it to provide the nice error display and to prevent form submit if there is an error, but am also using a remote call in conjuction with it which passes the values from the form to a custom script in our database which then returns a reply of {"valid":true} or {"valid":false} & an error accordingly. I'm beginning to wonder if that isn't our issue.

Comment: Why not just build that into the validation on the required fields using jQuery Validation (like min/max lengths, numerics, etc.)?  Then move those validation checks from xpath-evaluator.xqy to the form submit in process-form.xqy.  Then you're not relying on jQuery Validation, some external validation (which could ajax fail), then the actual submit (which again, should be validating user input anyway).

Comment: I'm not sure that's an option since we're attempting to validate XPath expressions against a custom schema and need to use that script. That said, I'm quite new to all of this so I could be mistaken. I may have to wait for a colleague of mine to return tomorrow and see if he thinks this is an option.

Comment: I leaning to believe that the xpath-evaluator.xqy is the cause of the problem since it does in fact validate & submit properly using the jsfiddle example.  Good luck!